# Run time error 424 object required when trying to trigger code

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to call a vba module when the user overwrites one of my formulas on a sheet. I think the Worksheet Change Event is triggering, but then I get the run time error 424 ("Object Required") when executing the module. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my Worksheet change event code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Award_Amount")) Is Nothing Then
Call Award_Amount_Entered
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Award_two_Amount")) Is Nothing Then
Call Award_two_Amount_Entered
End If
End Sub
```

Here's the code in the module I'm calling:

```
Sub Award_Amount_Entered()

    'If the user has overwritten the formula that was just in the cell

If ActiveCell.HasFormula = False Then
Applicaton.Intersect((Rows(ActiveCell.Row)), Range("AA:AA")).Select

....run some more code

End If

End Sub
```

When debugging, vba highlights the last line of the above code: Application.Intersect((Rows(ActiveCell.Row)),Range("AA:AA")).Select

I'm sure this used to work previously! Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this!

Tina

Comment: Try fully qualifying the rows property.

Comment: You also spelled Application wrong.

Comment: In the sheet code module, all Range() and  Cells() calls will default to the sheet object, but that's not true for code in a regular module, so it would be a good idea to be more specific there.

Comment: I **strongly** recommend including an `Option Explicit` as the first line in each of your code modules.  That will prevent this sort of error because it would have said `Variable not defined` as soon as it tried to compile the code, and would have highlighted `Applicaton` for you.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions commented in the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("Award_Amount"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Award_Amount_Entered rng     '<<< pass rng to the called procedure
    End If

    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("Award_two_Amount"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Award_two_Amount_Entered rng '<<< pass rng to the called procedure
    End If


End Sub
```

Called Sub:

```
Sub Award_Amount_Entered(rng As Range)

    Dim c As Range, c2 As Range

    'Remember, Target can be a multi-cell range, so loop over
    '   all of the cells in the "rng" parameter...

    On Error GoTo haveError 'handle any errors

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        'If the user has overwritten the formula that was just in the cell
        If Not c.HasFormula Then

            'Use a range variable instead of selecting the cell
            '  and then operating on the selection 
            Set c2 = c.EntireRow.Cells(1, "AA")

            'If you're going to update the sheet here then it's good practice
            '  to disable events
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            'update sheet
            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub

haveError:
    'If your code errors you need to make sure you re-enable events
    '  (at the very least) before exiting
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```